# Unable to display content inside a SwipeRow

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to wrap the data present in a list and make the list swipeable using SwipeRow. But after I add the SwipeRow on top of my ListItem tag, the content is not displayed.

I have tried using renderItem but that seems unrelatable and doesn't work.

```
return(
//  <SwipeRow style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}>
           //body={
                <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
            <ListItem style={{ width: '100%' }} onPress={() => this.navigationTo(this.props.data.h)}>
                <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 15, alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}>
                    {this.props.data.iconType === 'Material' ? (
                        <MaterialIcon style={{}} size={24} name={this.props.data.i} color="#87898B" />
                    ) : (
                            <MaterialCommunityIcons style={{}} size={24} name={this.props.data.i} color="#87898B" />
                        )}
                </View>

                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.heading}>{this.props.data.h}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.description}>
                        {this.props.data.dp}{' '}
                        <B>
                            {count} {this.props.data.db}
                        </B>{' '}
                        {this.props.data.da}.
          </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.metadata}>{this.props.data.m}</Text>
                </View>
            </ListItem>
            </View>
            //  }
            //  </SwipeRow>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably try giving some styles to `SwipeRow` assuming you have imported the swipeRow

Comment: Have already tried providing background color to it. The color shows up but not the content inside the list.

Comment: Try giving it some styles like justifyContent, flex etc

Comment: Doesn't work tried adding it. The content inside the body of SwipeRow doesn't display.

Comment: Try with only one child. Make sure the inner child gets the property of flex : 1 and give some color to the child

Answer (score 0):

You can use `renderRow` in `ListView`

```
<ListView
    style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor:'red'}}
    dataSource={this.props.data}
    renderRow={ data => (
        <SwipeRow
            leftOpenValue={75}
            rightOpenValue={-75}
        >
            <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 15, alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}>
                {this.props.data.iconType === 'Material' ? (
                    <MaterialIcon style={{}} size={24} name={data.i} color="#87898B" />
                ) : (
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons style={{}} size={24} name={data.i} color="#87898B" />
                    )}
            </View>

            <View>
                <Text style={styles.heading}>{data.h}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.description}>
                    {data.dp}{' '}
                    <B>
                        {count} {data.db}
                    </B>{' '}
                    {data.da}.
      </Text>
                <Text style={styles.metadata}>{data.m}</Text>
            </View>
        </SwipeRow>
    )}
/>
```